# Show that either $Ax=c$ or $A^{\top}y=0, c^{\top}y=1$ has a solution

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Im working on a problem but I don't know how to start with this.

$A\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times n},\;b\in\mathbb{R}^m, 0\neq c\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  Show that either the system $Ax=c$ or the system  $A^{\top}y=0$, $c^{\top}y=1$ has a solution.

How would you start this? I'd appreciate any hints or solutions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Once I see all these transposes, I think of inner products. Note that $\langle x,y\rangle=x^Ty$ for the usual Euclidean inner product in any dimension.

Assume $Ax=c$ has no solution. Then, let $P$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $Im(A):=\{Ax|x\in \mathbb{R}^m\}$. Note that $c-Pc$ is now orthogonal to $Im(A)$, hence, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$,

$$
\langle A^T(c-Pc), x\rangle=\langle c-Pc, Ax\rangle=0
$$
Since $x$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $c-Pc\in \mathrm{ker} A^T$. However, by the reverse triangle inequality
$$
\langle c,c-Pc\rangle=\|c\|^2-\langle c,Pc\rangle\geq \|c\|(\|c\|-\|Pc\|)>0,
$$
since $\|c\|^2=\|Pc\|^2+\|c-Pc\|^2$ by Pythagoras.
Thus, letting $y=\frac{1}{\langle c,c-Pc\rangle} (c-Pc)$ solves the desired equation.